# Partitioning tables with a timestamp column in PostgreSQL generates ERROR

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have created a dummy table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBD_partitioning_table (
    shop character varying(200),
    region character varying(200),
    sale_date date not null
) PARTITION BY LIST(sale_date);
```

The table should be partitioned per sale_date. When I trie to insert values on that table like:

```
INSERT INTO TBD_partitioning_table
VALUES ('A', 'LA', '2022-04-28'::date);
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR:  no partition of relation "tbd_partitioning_table" found for row
> DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (sale_date) = (2022-04-28).
> SQL state: 23514

Checking the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) of PostgreSQL I found out that I might first need to create a child table that will include the partition of the parent table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBD_partitioning_table_20220428 PARTITION OF TBD_partitioning_table
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-04-28') TO ('2022-04-28');
```

Given that I will insert-append the parent table once per day with the current date, is it efficient to create a different child table each day to hold the date loaded?

Moreover, since I am not aware of an automated way to create generated table names from functions in postgreSQL, creating a different table like `CREATE TABLE TBD_partitioning_table_{current_date::date}` is not quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with variable name in a function if you use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.

Yes, you need to create a partition *before* you insert data for that partition. About partitioning per day, I would consider how long the data should be retained. You should not have too many partitions, otherwise query planning will become quite slow.

Comment: Indeed day to day partitioning won't be much efficient for query planning. However, given that per day I expect approximately 200,000 records, I wanted the table to be partitioned on day level. Another case would be the partitioning in Month level, giving 200,000 *30 total records per partition.

Comment: 200000 rows is a tiny table. Use a partition per month or year.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TBD_partitioning_table_20220428 PARTITION OF TBD_partitioning_table
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-04-28') TO ('2022-04-28');
```

Will not work. because it's **empty** range.
You can use list partition.
[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3953d58153c6ed9520f1892d2a0de098)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBD_partitioning_table (
    shop text,
    region text,
    sale_date date not null
) PARTITION BY list(sale_date);
```

script for generating partitions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generate_partitioned_tables (_begindate date, _enddate date)
    AS $$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
    loopdate date DEFAULT _begindate;
BEGIN
    IF _begindate > _enddate THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '_begindate should smaller than _end_date';
    END IF;
    IF _begindate is null or _enddate is null THEN
        raise exception '_begindate and _enddate cannot be null';
    end if;
    while loopdate <= _enddate LOOP
        _sql := 'CREATE TABLE TBD_partitioning_table_'
                    || to_char(loopdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
                    || ' partition of TBD_partitioning_table for values in ( '''
                    || loopdate || ''')';
        RAISE NOTICE '_sql:  %', _sql;
        EXECUTE _sql;
        SELECT
            (loopdate + interval '1 day') INTO loopdate;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the detailed answer + the automated procedure. I have two questions. 
1) Your code generates a new table for a given date? i.e 2022-04-28? 
2) If I wanted to replace the day level with month level could i just replace ```for values in ( ''' loopdate ''')``` with ```for values from loopdate to _enddate``` where loopdate is ```TO_DATE(CONCAT(date_part('year', loopdate),'-',date_part('month', loopdate),'-01'),'YYYY-MM-DD')``` and _enddate is similar to loopdate but ```+ interval '1 month'```

Comment: yes. generate table for everyday belong to  range(_begindate, _enddate) inclusive. 
if you want to partition by month then things would be a little bit different. but it's not that hard.